# SQL Server : create summarization based on multiple dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have the following table containing positions for workers dated back by 10 years:

| worker_id | position_code | date_from | date_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x1 | 2021-01-01 | 2100-12-31 |
| 1 | x2 | 2020-12-01 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | x3 | 2000-01-01 | 2100-12-31 |

I want to create a view, where I can see for each worker what their position for every month.

So for example:

| year | month | worker_id | position_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 12 | 1 | x2 |
| 2020 | 12 | 2 | x3 |
| 2021 | 1 | 1 | x1 |
| 2021 | 1 | 2 | x3 |
| 2021 | 2 | 1 | x1 |

Ideally I'm only interested on the last 6 month to have better performance.
overall there is ~10000 workers, and the table itself around ~100000 lines.
for some workers there is only 1 position, but it can be multiple.

In theory position is only changing at the beginning of months, but would be better to watch for this as well, and in this case take the which is active at the end of the month.

(so for example: from jan 1-10 position is x1, from jan 10-to 31 x2, in this case x2 is the one I'm looking for)

Comment: What happens if a worker starts in the middle of a month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH WORKERS(worker_id,     position_code,  date_from,  date_to) AS
(

  SELECT 1 ,    'x1',   '2021-01-01',   '2100-12-31' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 ,    'x2' ,  '2020-12-01',   '2021-01-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 ,    'x3' ,  '2000-01-01' ,  '2100-12-31' 
),
MINI_MAX AS
(
  SELECT MIN(DATE_FROM)AS STARTT_DATE,MAX(DATE_TO)AS END_DATE
    FROM WORKERS
),
CALENDAR AS
(
  SELECT CAST(STARTT_DATE AS DATE)DATE_D FROM MINI_MAX AS W
     UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,Z.DATE_D)
    FROM CALENDAR AS Z
    WHERE Z.DATE_D<=(SELECT END_DATE FROM MINI_MAX)
),
RESULT AS
(
   SELECT YEAR(C.DATE_D)AS YEARR,MONTH(C.DATE_D)MONTHH,W.worker_id,W.position_code
    FROM CALENDAR AS C 
    JOIN WORKERS AS W ON C.DATE_D BETWEEN W.date_from AND W.date_to
)
SELECT R.YEARR,R.MONTHH,R.worker_id,R.position_code
 FROM RESULT AS R
  OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

I would say that the most suitable way for this kind of queries is to use a permanent calendar table and perform JOIN directly to it

Comment: thanks looks good and fast. 
i can filter the last select for month, year i need i guess ?
what happens if for a worker there is 2 value for the same month ?

Comment: I guess, it would be better to replace all these calculations with join to calendar table.After that all filtering for year,month etc will be trivial. If a worker has 2 values for the same month you will get 2 records

Answer (score 0):

The hard part is generating the months.  One method is a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select worker_id, position_code, date_from as dte,
             eomonth(case when date_to < eomonth(getdate()) then dateadd(day, -1, date_to) else getdate() end) as date_to
      from t
      union all
      select worker_id, position_code,
             dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(year(dte), month(dte), 1)), date_to
      from cte
      where eomonth(dte) < eomonth(date_to)
    )
select *
from cte
order by worker_id, dte desc
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Note:  You might get duplicates if a worker starts a position in the middle of a month.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a6f602e2689c9714a0cd1d84e6a3b1a0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thanks this looks clear. i have 2 questions:
since i dont need the full range, i can filter the whole cte ? for example for this year ? or performance wise better to try to do it before the uninon?
if there are multiple values for a month like you said, whats the best way to filter ? order by date_to and take only the first row ?

Comment: @meri . . . If you only want a range, I might suggest that you ask a *new* question.  That would be a bit simpler.  But. yes, you can generate all the data and then filter afterwards.